# RabbitMQ server shutting down shortly after starting

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I'm having some trouble with keeping RabbitMQ up.

I start it via the provided `/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start`, and it starts up fine. `status` shows that it's fine.

But after a while, the server dies. `status` prints

```
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@myserver': nodedown
```

Checking the log file, it seems I've reached the memory threshold. Here are the logs:

```
    # start
=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:24:13 ===
Limiting to approx 924 file handles (829 sockets)

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:24:13 ===
Memory limit set to 723MB of 1807MB total.

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:24:13 ===
Disk free limit set to 953MB

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:24:13 ===
Management plugin upgraded statistics to fine.

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:24:13 ===
msg_store_transient: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:24:13 ===
msg_store_persistent: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index

=WARNING REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:24:13 ===
msg_store_persistent: rebuilding indices from scratch

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:24:27 ===
started TCP Listener on [::]:5672

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:24:27 ===
Management agent started.

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:24:27 ===
Management plugin started. Port: 55672, path: /

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:24:39 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1999.0> (127.0.0.1:34788 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:24:40 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.1999.0> (127.0.0.1:34788 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:24:42 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.2035.0> (127.0.0.1:34791 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:24:46 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.2072.0> (127.0.0.1:34792 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:25:19 ===
vm_memory_high_watermark set. Memory used:768651448 allowed:758279372

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:25:19 ===
    alarm_handler: {set,{{resource_limit,memory,'rabbit@myserver'},
                         []}}

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::03:25:48 ===
Statistics database started.
    # server dies here
```

I seem to have been reaching the memory threshold, but reading the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory-use.html), it shouldn't shutdown the server? Just prevent publishing until some memory is freed up?

And yes, I am aware that my celery workers *are* the cause of the memory usage, I'd just thought that RabbitMQ would handle it correctly, which the docs seem to imply. So I'm doing something wrong?

**EDIT**: Refactored my task so it's message is just a single string (max 15 chars). Doesn't seem to be making any difference.

I tried starting RabbitMQ and `celery worker --purge`, with no events coming in to trigger the tasks, but it seems RabbitMQ's memory usage still steadily climbs to 40%. It then crashes shortly afterwards. It crashes, with none of my tasks having the chance to run.

Comment: I am not sure what distro you are using but I would recommend starting RMQ as a service. eg sudo service rabbitmq-server start.  Also there are RMQ error logs in /var/log/rabbitmq, I think you might find more information there.

Comment: Turns out the RabbitMQ from Ubuntu's repositoriy is *really* old. I installed from RabbitMQ's repo and it's good now.

Comment: yes you need to read RMQs docs on how to install the latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating RabbitMQ to official stable version fixed the issue. The RabbitMQ package in Ubuntu 12.04's repository was *really* old.